# jquery: toggle a fieldset based upon a specific checked checkbox in an array of multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery

Using jquery, given **multiple** checkboxes, how please would we toggle a fieldset on/off if a **particular** checkbox is checked/ unchecked? (more than one checkbox may be chosen as this is multiple)

I've tried using ':checked' and 'jQuery.inArray' together with toggle() but no luck yet. 
Example HTML without the script:

```
<form>

 Which food group do you like?
 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrition[]" value="Fruit">
 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrition[]" value="Vegetables">
 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrition[]" value="Sweets">

<!-- show this input (toggle on/off) only if 'Fruit' is one of the checked boxes-->
<fieldset id="someid" style="display:none;>
 You chose Fruit! Name one fruit: <input type="text" name= "afruit" />
</fieldset>

</form>
```

?

here is the complete html + script based on Jason P's answer, using id as selector:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
$('#fruitid').change(function(e) {
    $('#someid').toggle(this.checked);
});
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
 Which food group do you like?
 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrition[]" value="Fruit" id="fruitid">
 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrition[]" value="Vegetables">
 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrition[]" value="Sweets">

<!-- show this input (toggle on/off) only if 'Fruit' is one of the checked boxes-->
<fieldset id="someid" style="display:none;">
 You chose Fruit! Name one fruit: <input type="text" name= "afruit" />
</fieldset>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show/Hide Field using Jquery based on user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471574/show-hide-field-using-jquery-based-on-user-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[value="Fruit"]').change(function(e) {
    $('#someid').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Might be a good idea to add a class or id to the "Fruits" checkbox so you can use a better selector.

Comment: Please would you show the script using an id such as <input type="checkbox" name="nutrition[]" value="Fruit" id="fruitid">
Also, how would one specify the checkbox name in addition to input[value="Fruit"] ... for example input[name='nutrition[]'] ...

Comment: The jQuery learning site is very helpful. What you're looking for is the first example: `$('#fruitid')` http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/.

Comment: Oh, upon submit various entries are validated. If the form is again displayed, the checked boxes correctly remain checked (not related to this post) but now the fieldsets are no longer shown even tho the boxes are checked. How would this be solved please? (I tried the same code with .submit added but no luck.) ps. not sure if this should be a whole new question ...

Comment: You would need to run the existing change logic on page load as well.

Comment: tried using $(window).ready(function(){ .. but that's not working. please elaborate.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { $('#someid').toggle($('#fruitid').prop('checked')); });` should work.

Comment: Yes, it does! :-) Now I'm trying to incorporate it into Typo3. New question opened here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909532/using-jquery-ready-to-manipulate-chained-checkboxes-within-typo3

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="nutrition[]" value="Fruit" class="fruit">
```

JS

```
$(".fruit").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){  
        $("#someid").css("display","block");
    }else{
        $("#someid").css("display","none");
    }
});
```

**Note:** i have added the class attribute to the checkbox so same as above you can do for each checkbox.

Comment: thank you. the if else statement makes it easy to read however there seems to be a small bug somewhere. can't get it to work.

Comment: can you tell me what error you got when you use the above code?

Comment: sure - the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7AtGg/
the '#solmeid' input does not toggle

Comment: i have updated my answer please use now it will surly work i have tried it. its my syntax error i forget to put ':checked' in single quote.

Comment: yes, that's it. http://jsfiddle.net/7AtGg/1/
Maybe this can also be solved: upon submit, in order to validate the form entries, the '#someid' fieldset no longer shows even tho' the related checkbox/s is/are checked.  the same issue with Jason P's solution. any ideas please?

Comment: then do upvote because it may be useful for other too if they find this answer as upvoted.