# jQuery .hide(), then .show() based on text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using a [jQuery filter example I found](http://resource.grapii.com/files/jQueryFilter/ulExample.html). Here is [my live example](http://www.evanwknight.com/gamestore/indexxxx.html).  Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/evanknight/pen/Ffjqp), (also the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nYYBU/1/) if you don't like CodePen).

After typing something in the input, the boxes do realign and the numbers dissapear.  However, when you delete the text you inputted, the numbers do not reappear unless you refresh the page.  I tried messing around with the code below but wasn't having any luck. Thanks for you help!

```
    $('#sortable').change(
function(){
if ($(this).val().length) {
    $('#number').hide();
}
else {
    $('#number').show();
}
```

});

Comment: I have looked at a few posts, including this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471574/show-hide-field-using-jquery-based-on-user-input

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nYYBU/8/
    its working now...
    i dont understand what really tryin to do...
    let me kno if this change was wat u wanted

Comment: No sorry, @Shashank. Thank you though!

Comment: ugh rando y u downvote me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/nYYBU/10/

**JS:-**

```
(function ($) {
    jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function (a, i, m) {
        return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };

    function listFilter(header, list) {
        var form = $("<form>").attr({
            "class": "filterform",
                "action": "#"
        }),
            input = $("<input>").attr({
                "class": "filterinput",
                    "type": "text",
            });
        $(form).append(input).appendTo(header);
        $(input).change(function () {
            var list = $("#sortable");
            var filter = $(this).val();
            console.log(filter.length);
            if (filter.length > 0) {
                $(list).find("a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
                $(".number").hide();
                $(".numberstwo").hide();
            } else {
                console.log($(".number"));
                $(".number").show();
                $(".numberstwo").show();
                $(list).find("a").parent().slideDown();
            }
            return false;
        }).keyup(function () {
            $(this).change();

        });
    }
    $(function () {
        listFilter($("#header"), $("#sortable"));

    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I'm now running into a problem once I removed the columns and made everything float: left.  Here is my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nYYBU/12/.  Once you type, then delete all the text from the input, there are 6 boxes on the top line, it doesn't reset to 4 and 4.

Comment: Actually, if you type in any letter in the input then delete it, it only shows one box now.

Comment: I've selected your answer, since it did work for the columns! Any help on the float would be very appreciated. I created a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286371/jquery-draggable-float-left-not-reseting-after-keyup

Answer (score 1):

Here's updated js...

Checkout [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nYYBU/9/)

```
(function ($) {
    jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function (a, i, m) {
        return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };

    function listFilter(header, list) {
        var form = $("<form>").attr({
            "class": "filterform",
                "action": "#"
        }),
            input = $("<input>").attr({
                "class": "filterinput",
                    "type": "text",
            });
        $(form).append(input).appendTo(header);
        $(input).change(function () {
            var filter = $(this).val();
            if (filter) {
                $(list).find("a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
                $(list).find("a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
            } else {
                $(list).find("li").slideDown();
            }
            return false;
        }).keyup(function () {
            $(this).change();
            if ($(this).val().length) {
                $('.number').hide();
            } else {
                $('.number').show();
            }

        });
    }
    $(function () {
        listFilter($("#header"), $("#sortable"));

    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: @ewk53 - Once you remove the filters, it doesn't restore all the `li's` back.

Answer (score 0):

To check the entered text I normally use keyup.
Change is not triggered when the user types something but when he types and exits the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sortable').blur(function(){
var len = $(this).val().length;
if (len) {
    $('#number').hide();
}
else {
    $('#number').show();
}
```